# How to split a dynamic string and assign variables to each word?

Tags: makefile

I have a requirement to capture a test name from a path and use it to create a directory using makefile. Below is the code which i tried so far. Below code working for fixed "test_path" length.

**%cat Makefile**

```
    test_path := /dir1/dir2/dir3/test.sv

test_split := $(subst /, ,$(test_path:v%=%))

test_a := $(word 1,$(test_split))
test_b := $(word 2,$(test_split))
test_c := $(word 3,$(test_split))
test_d := $(word 4,$(test_split))
test_d_split := $(subst ., ,$(test_d:v%=%))
test_d_1 := $(word 1,$(test_d_split))

all:
    echo test_split = $(test_split)
    echo test_a = $(test_a)
    echo test_b = $(test_b)
    echo test_c = $(test_c)
    echo test_d = $(test_d)
    echo test_d = $(test_d)
    echo test_d_1 = $(test_d_1)
    mkdir $(test_d_1)
```

We are successfully creating a test directory using the above code, but we need to handle paths of different lengths. How can we do that?

Results:

used fixed length test_path := /dir1/dir2/dir3/test.sv -> working fine

if test_path is updated test_path := /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/test.sv
% mkdir dir4 -> creating dir4 as directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to achieve is not 100% clear. If the test directory you want to create is the filename with all suffixes removed (e.g., `test` when `test_path = a/b/c/test.1.2.3`) and if you use GNU make you could try:

```
all:
    mkdir -p $(word 1,$(subst ., ,$(notdir $(test_path))))
```

Note the `-p` option of `mkdir` to ignore the error when the directory already exists.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to choose the last element of the path, and use that, less any filename extension, as the name for a directory.  I would not approach that even *remotely* like the example code.

The shell is better suited for this than is `make` itself, and you can use that in your makefile.  For example,

```
test_path = /dir1/dir2/dir3/test.sv

all:
        file=$$(basename '$(test_path)'); mkdir "$${file/.*}"
```

The `basename` command extracts the last component from a path.  The `${file/.*}` is expanded (by the shell) to the value of (shell) variable `file`, less the longest substring starting with a `.` character.  To pass a `$` through to the shell, it must be doubled to prevent `make` from interpreting it.

If you are for some reason constrained to use GNU-specific `make` functions to do the text manipulations, then it has `$(notdir)` for extracting the filename portion of a path, and `$(basename)` for removing filename extensions (note the unfortunate difference between the action of this `basename` function and the shell command of the same name).  You might use these like so:

```
test_path := /dir1/dir2/dir3/test.sv

dirname := $(notdir $(basename $(test_path)))

all:
        mkdir '$(dirname)'
```

Comment: `$(basename ...)` only removes the suffix -- it does not remove the directory`

Comment: Thank you, @HardcoreHenry.  Clearly I was focusing too closely on the shell. I have revised that part of this answer, though I still think that at least in the example case, the wanted behavior is best approached via the shell, not via `make`.

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret your question correctly, you would want to do:

```
testdir := /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir_n/foo.bar
all: 
    mkdir -p $(basename $(notdir $(testdir)))
```

This would make directory `foo` for the above value of testdir.   See [filename functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html) for more information on these

Note, if you want to strip all suffixes (i.e. your filname is `/dirs/test.foo.bar`, and you just want `test`, you could do:

```
all:
    mkdir -p $(firstword $(subst ., ,$(notdir $(testdir))))
```

Comment: `basename` removes only the last suffix. Not sure the OP want to create directory `test.a` when the filename is `test.a.b`. As their attempts suggest they probably want just `test`.

Comment: That's a good point....  Updating answer

Comment: Also incorporating your suggestion of adding a `-p` in there, in case directory already exists